# Make a GridView a static width and force horizontal scrolling

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Alright, so I've got an ASP.NET `GridView` which of course generates a `table`. This `table` is inside of a `div` that has a static width of let's say `673px`. However, it doesn't seem to matter what I do, I can't get this `table` to stay within those dimensions and scroll horizontally.

Here is the HTML with the style inline:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style>
        *
        {
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 0px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-right: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
        html
        {
            color: #000;
            font-size: 12px;
            border-top-color: currentColor;
            border-right-color: currentColor;
            border-bottom-color: currentColor;
            border-left-color: currentColor;
            border-top-width: 0px;
            border-right-width: 0px;
            border-bottom-width: 0px;
            border-left-width: 0px;
            border-top-style: none;
            border-right-style: none;
            border-bottom-style: none;
            border-left-style: none;
        }
        body
        {
            background-color: rgb(237, 237, 237);
        }
        a
        {
            color: #154995;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .d-outer
        {
            width: 958px;
            text-align: left;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-left: auto;
        }
        .d-inner
        {
            width: 958px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 0px;
            float: left;
            background-image: url("../images/base/inner_bg.gif");
            background-attachment: scroll;
            background-repeat: repeat-y;
            background-position-x: left;
            background-position-y: top;
            background-size: auto;
            background-origin: padding-box;
            background-clip: border-box;
            background-color: transparent;
        }
        .d-innerCont
        {
            width: 908px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-right: 25px;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            padding-left: 25px;
            float: left;
        }
        .d-main
        {
            width: 908px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 0px;
            float: left;
        }
        .d-left
        {
            width: 665px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-right: 23px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 10px;
            float: left;
        }
        .gridViewStyle
        {
            width: 630px;
            overflow: scroll;
        }
        .gridViewStyle th, .gridViewStyle td
        {
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
        .d-dataGridCont
        {
            width: 665px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            float: left;
        }
        .d-dataGridBody
        {
            width: 665px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 0px;
            float: left;
            background-image: url("../images/base/data_grid_bg.gif");
            background-attachment: scroll;
            background-repeat: repeat-y;
            background-position-x: left;
            background-position-y: top;
            background-size: auto;
            background-origin: padding-box;
            background-clip: border-box;
            background-color: transparent;
        }
        .d-dataGridBodyRow
        {
            width: 637px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-right: 14px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 14px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();"
    method="post">
    <div class="d-outer">
        <div class="d-inner">
            <div class="d-innerCont">
                <div class="d-main">
                    <div class="d-left">
                        <div class="d-dataGridCont">
                            <div class="d-dataGridBody">
                                <div class="d-dataGridBodyRow">
                                    <div id="ctl00_formContent_PaymentsDiv">
                                        <div>
                                            <table class="gridViewStyle" id="ctl00_formContent_grdPayments" style="width: 95%;
                                                color: #333333; font-family: Lato; border-top-color: #c8c8c8; border-right-color: #c8c8c8;
                                                border-bottom-color: #c8c8c8; border-left-color: #c8c8c8; border-top-width: 2px;
                                                border-right-width: 2px; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-left-width: 2px; border-top-style: solid;
                                                border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid;
                                                border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                <tbody style="">
                                                    <tr align="center" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(36, 97, 191);">
                                                        <td colspan="6">
                                                            <table border="0">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span>1</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$2')">
                                                                                2</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$3')">
                                                                                3</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$4')">
                                                                                4</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$5')">
                                                                                5</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$6')">
                                                                                6</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$7')">
                                                                                7</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$8')">
                                                                                8</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$9')">
                                                                                9</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$10')">
                                                                                10</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$11')">
                                                                                ...</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr style="color: #333333; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; white-space: nowrap;
                                                        background-color: white;">
                                                        <th scope="col">
                                                            Issued Date
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th scope="col">
                                                            Customer
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th scope="col">
                                                            Vehicle Type
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th scope="col">
                                                            Claim #
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th scope="col">
                                                            Amount
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th scope="col">
                                                            Status
                                                        </th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr style="font-family: Lato; font-size: 16px; white-space: nowrap; background-color: rgb(226, 237, 243);">
                                                        <td>
                                                            2012/11/12
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            Bob's Repair
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            1999 Chevrolet Lumina
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            4687426946874269
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td align="right">
                                                            $409,714.00
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            ISSUED
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr align="center" style="color: white; background-color: rgb(36, 97, 191);">
                                                        <td colspan="6">
                                                            <table border="0">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <span>1</span>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$2')">
                                                                                2</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$3')">
                                                                                3</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$4')">
                                                                                4</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$5')">
                                                                                5</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$6')">
                                                                                6</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$7')">
                                                                                7</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$8')">
                                                                                8</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$9')">
                                                                                9</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$10')">
                                                                                10</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td>
                                                                            <a style="color: white;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$formContent$grdPayments','Page$11')">
                                                                                ...</a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***What I need to get in the end is the `table` to adhere to the static width of its container and scroll both the header and row data horizontally.***

I thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put overflow:auto; in the .d-dataGridBody

```
       .d-dataGridBody
        {
            width: 665px;
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
            padding-left: 0px;
            float: left;
            background-image: url("../images/base/data_grid_bg.gif");
            background-attachment: scroll;
            background-repeat: repeat-y;
            background-position-x: left;
            background-position-y: top;
            background-size: auto;
            background-origin: padding-box;
            background-clip: border-box;
            background-color: transparent;
            overflow:auto;
        }
```